# I want to be able to print stack traces java style in c

Tags: c, reflection

Simple question, I want to be able to print stack traces java style in c. I have the signal handlers set up and I get the stack trace addresses but I want to translate the addresses to the function names. Therefore, I decided to implement reflection. Right now I have tables as follows: {"FOO", &FOO, "BAR", &BAR}. While this solution works for all platforms, it is really annoying to keep up to date. Is there another way to do this (one that wouldnt require manual upkeep?)

Comment: The data has to be stored somewhere. You could make macros for it, and call it like `REFLECTION_DATA(FOO), REFLECTION_DATA(BAR)` etc.

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you just by looking at that problem description. What is it really you're trying to do? Please be more specific.

Comment: You can not do reflection in C. Regarding the question on whether there is another way of what you are doing you need to give more details regarding what you are doing.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what your question is about. Please put a little more effort into it, if you don't wat to get it closed.

Comment: Sounds like you want debug symbols in your binary and access to them...

Comment: There are some platform-specific solutions, but there is no cross-platform one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm think http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html you can found answer to this question.

```
 #include <execinfo.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 /* Obtain a backtrace and print it to stdout. */
 void
 print_trace (void)
 {
   void *array[10];
   size_t size;
   char **strings;
   size_t i;

   size = backtrace (array, 10);
   strings = backtrace_symbols (array, size);

   printf ("Obtained %zd stack frames.\n", size);

   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
      printf ("%s\n", strings[i]);

   free (strings);
 }

 /* A dummy function to make the backtrace more interesting. */
 void
 dummy_function (void)
 {
   print_trace ();
 }

 int
 main (void)
 {
   dummy_function ();
   return 0;
 }
```

there is example from this page, make sure you compile it with -rdynamic flag otherwise you will get backtrack of addresses instead of function names :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to keep track of the tables yourself, the linker will do that for you already. It's called the 'symbol table'. You can configure your compiler/linker to include this table in the final output or leave it out. You could use that table to lookup the function names when walking the stack.

If you want **easy** stack tracing in C, use a debugger like GDB. Otherwise, there are already libraries and other solutions that provide this functionality. Look at this one for example: http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at solutions offered here: 
http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/219429-stacktrace-code-snippet-like-gdbs-bt

or here:
http://tlug.up.ac.za/wiki/index.php/Obtaining_a_stack_trace_in_C_upon_SIGSEGV

Answer (score 0):

You could use the conventions in GObject Introspection: http://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection