# Can I find what type does a variable belongs, in C?

Tags: c, reflection

I'm a novice in C, and since C does some implict changing at times, I often get confused. I'm getting confused in what `type`(like `int,char`) does the operation(`+,-`) returns. So in C, I want to know what `type` a variable belongs to at any point in a program. That is in Java we call it as Reflection and we can get all the information of our programs at runtime.

Now in C is there any lib that does the similar job of Reflection API in java. Or there is any trick in C, that can be used to find what type does a particular variable belongs to?

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to get that information at **Run-Time**?

Comment: Are you asking specifically a C question? Should remove the C++ tag otherwise you may get answers that are C++-specific.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag since this is about C.

Comment: Various duplicates and near duplicates from the "related" sidebar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353022/reflection-support-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497328/how-to-do-reflection-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312493/does-c-already-have-some-kind-of-reflection

Comment: cheap trick: `typedef struct {} X;` and then `X x = expression`; and then read the error message ;)

Comment: It might be worth elaborating **why** you would have need for such a thing. Usually the answer points suggests that your design isn't  quite idiomatic C and could be improved.

Comment: @Ant's: I didn't downvote or closevote this, but if you're looking for an explanation: I imagine that it's because people feel that you're asking this question only because of your lack of knowledge of C, and once you know C a bit better, you wouldn't even ask this question. Therefore it's considered a question of low value to others. Don't let that discourage you! Keep on learning, and do feel free to come back for further questions.

Comment: Let me get this straight: People downvote because the guy who writes the question doesn't know the answer?   That seems outright... arrogant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C and C++ are statically typed languages, so there is no reflection and no library for type discovery. In C, you just have to read the standard and understand the type promotion rules. Luckily, that's a finite amount of information that you should be able to grasp quickly.

In the new C++11, there's the `decltype` keyword which returns the type of the expression, so you can say `decltype(x + y) z = x + y;` to declare `z` to be of the type of the expression `x + y`. This is a compile-time construction, though, so this is merely a shortcut to something you could have inferred by other means.

Comment: Uh, Java is statically typed and has reflection. Whether a language has "reflection" built in is a matter what the language and compiler guys decided would be available for introspective queries at runtime.

Comment: @Ira: I would really hesitate to call Java "statically typed". I mean, yes, for ints and doubles, fair enough. But look at just any container, for example - Java classes basically consist exclusively of all-virtual functions and what C++ would call `dynamic_cast`s.

Comment: Statically typed means in principle that every entity has a known type at compile time, and generally that the compiler checks that what is used has a type compatible (for some definition of "compatible") with the place it is used. In Java, most methods don't accept just Object; they often accept a detailed specialization of it. I wouldn't hesitate for a minute to call Java statically typed. Neither does the rest of the world: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: @Ira: Out of curiosity: Does Java's reflection work for primitive (value) types like `int` and `double`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `#include <typeinfo>` you can then use `typeid` to get the variable type.

Comment: @psycho: ah, I thought there was a C version of it but I was wrong.

Comment: @Nicholas: You may have mixed up with `typeof`?

Comment: "typeof" isn't standard C, its a GCCism.

Answer (score 0):

If your implementation supports C++ ABI, you can use it to print out expression types.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cxxabi.h>

int main ()
{
    int status;
    char* mytypename = abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid((2+'x')*0.9f).name(), 0, 0, 
                                             &status);
    if (mytypename && status == 0)
    {
        std::cout << mytypename << std::endl;
        std::free (mytypename);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Error determining type name, status is " 
                   << status << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Such things are useful mostly for educational purposes. There's not much you can do with them, apart from looking and learning.

Comment: The OP isn't interested in C++.